# MySQL InnoDB Fast Index Creation does not work

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a InnoDB table with about 20,000,000 records and I want to add some indexes on it. Since I have a lot of queries on this table on different columns, I know that multi columns indexes will be better than single in this case. So I created indexes by `Fast Index Creation` technique as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE mtTBL 
ADD INDEX `index1`  (`col09`,`col03`,`col02`),
ADD INDEX `index2`  (`col09`,`col03`),
ADD INDEX `index3`  (`col09`,`col03`,`col07`),
ADD INDEX `index4`  (`col09`,`col03`,`col12`),
ADD INDEX `index5`  (`col03`),
ADD INDEX `index6`  (`col09`),
ADD INDEX `index7`  (`col09`,`col07`),
ADD INDEX `index8`  (`col09`,`col12`),
ADD INDEX `index9`  (`col09`,`col04`),
ADD INDEX `index10` (`col09`,`col13`),
ADD INDEX `index11` (`col09`,`col06`),
ADD INDEX `index12` (`col09`,`col02`),
ADD INDEX `index13` (`col09`,`col06`,`col08`,`col10`);
```

But I saw that it takes about 8 minutes and is similar to when I add indexes one by one. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

- Did it appear to be waiting for one index to finish before the next? (This might indicate that fast index creation is fast for only one.)
- What version of MySQL are you using?  (There may be a further improvement in a newer version.)
- That is a "too many" indexes.  Please discuss what the table has in it, and why you think you need that many indexes.  (There may be a workaround.)
- It may be beneficial if you have `col09` as the first column in the `PRIMARY KEY`.  (What is the PK now?)
- Why does the 8 minutes matter?  You won't be adding indexes every day.
- Go through the stackoverflow tutorials so you can get enough 'reputation' to answer my questions.

Answer (score -1):

I know this does not solve your problem but your indexes are redundant. Index is read from the left. So first index cover all cases for next indexes. If you Select with col09 then first index is used. Same for col09, col03 etc.

ADD INDEX `index1`  (`col09`,`col03`,`col02`),
ADD INDEX `index2`  (`col09`,`col03`),
ADD INDEX `index5`  (`col03`),
ADD INDEX `index6`  (`col09`),

Comment: Hi.  Your answer sound like a comment.  It is best to post comments as comments useing the `Add a Comment` link.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Unfortunetly I dont have enough reputation to add comment :/